# Gnumeric summing relative values

Tags: gnumeric

I have 57 rows with numbers in cells D through S. I would like to add those numbers up and include the sum in T. So T2 would be the sum of the numbers in D2 to S2, and T3 would be the sum of the numbers in D3 to S3. Rather than type 57 different formulas, I want one formula that will work wherever I paste it.

I've looked at the Gnumeric documentation, and I see a "row_num" variable, which I think is what I want, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: maybe: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/gnumeric.html#gnumeric-function-SUM ?

Answer (score 0):

in  T, just type "=sum(D2:S2)" and copy to the cells below, the formula will be updated for each line.